# Dividing decimals yields invalid results in Python 2.5 to 2.7

Tags: python, numbers, decimal

After a very thorough read of the Python's [decimal module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html), I still find myself puzzled by what happens when I divide a decimal.

In Python 2.4.6 (makes sense):

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(1000) / 10
Decimal("100")
```

In Python 2.5.6, Python 2.6.7, and Python 2.7.2 (puzzling):

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(1000) / 10
Decimal('0.00000-6930898827444486144')
```

More confusing yet, that result doesn't even appear to be valid:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal('0.00000-6930898827444486144')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 548, in __new__
    "Invalid literal for Decimal: %r" % value)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 3844, in _raise_error
    raise error(explanation)
decimal.InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: '0.00000-6930898827444486144'
```

The result is the same using `decimal.Decimal(1000) / decimal.Decimal(10)`, so it's not an issue with using an int as the divisor.

Part of the issue is clearly around precision:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal("1000.000") / decimal.Decimal("10.000")
Decimal('0.00000-6930898827444486144')
>>> decimal.Decimal("1000.000") / decimal.Decimal("10")
Decimal('0.000200376420520689664')
```

But there should be *ample* precision in `decimal.Decimal("1000.000")` to divide safely by 10 and get an answer that's at least in the right ballpark.

The fact that this behavior is unchanged through three major revisions of Python says to me that it is not a bug.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

How can I divide a decimal (short of using Python 2.4)?

Comment: Even if it's not a bug, _someone_ has probably opened a bug report about it at some point in the last 5 years on http://bugs.python.org, I would take a look there

Comment: Good point. I searched there; all my search fu turned up that looked remotely related were http://bugs.python.org/issue7046 and http://bugs.python.org/issue1031480, neither of which is this...

Comment: Works fine for me on Ubuntu 11.04 with Python 2.6.6 and 2.7.1+. Could it be a macports issue?

Comment: I think @user500198 is onto something.  It works fine for me on Windows XP.

Comment: @user500198 could be -- I found an Ubuntu instance to test on, and I can't reproduce it there using either 2.6.5 or 2.7.2. I'm a bit puzzled as to how MacPorts could matter, since the decimal module is pure Python, but that's a good start...I'll poke at it some.

Comment: Confirmed -- installing Python 2.7.2 from source fixes the issue. Appears to be MacPorts. Will file a bug. Sigh.

Comment: Filed MacPorts bug https://trac.macports.org/ticket/31444. Will update with comments here as events warrant; will answer-and-close when this is resolved.

Comment: FWIW, with current MacPorts Python 2.7.2's installed on both 10.6.8 and 10.7.1 I get the correct results.  Don't know what might have done wrong for you but you might reconsider rebuilding the Python port and all of its dependent ports.

Comment: @NedDeily it looks like it may have to do with the compiler used. Are you using Xcode 3.x? (See the MacPorts bug.) I just reinstalled 2.5, and am getting the same results. (2.7 has too many critical dependencies for me to reinstall it fully right now.)

Comment: Yes, I am using Xcode 3 for 10.6 as I noted on the bug.  You may be able to work around with 10.6 Xcode 4 by ensuring the Python build uses gcc-4.2 rather than clang.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your MacPorts bug, you have installed Xcode 4 and your version of Python 2.7.2 was built with the clang C compiler, rather than gcc-4.2.  There is at least [one known problem with building with clang](http://bugs.python.org/issue11149) on OS X that has been fixed in Python subsequent to the 2.7.2. release.  Either apply the patch or, better, ensure the build uses gcc-4.2.  Something like (untested!):

```
sudo bash
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
port clean python27
port upgrade --force python27
```

prior to the build *might* work if MacPorts doesn't override it.

UPDATE: The required patch has now been applied to the MacPorts port files for Python 2.  See https://trac.macports.org/changeset/87442

Comment: I think this is the right track to pursue. However, I've tried exporting CC, CXX, and CPP=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2, but haven't had any luck yet. https://trac.macports.org/wiki/UsingTheRightCompiler suggests I may have do some extra digging under the hood. Will keep working on this...

Comment: For reference, the way to set the compiler that worked for me was `configure.compiler gcc-4.2` -- see https://trac.macports.org/ticket/31444#comment:8.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:
For python 2.7.3 compiled with clang (via Homebrew on OS X), this seems to be fixed.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct 10 2012, 13:00:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(1000) / 10
Decimal('100')
```