# Why is decimal.Decimal returning scientific notation for a simple calculation?

Tags: python

I'm having a weird issue on one of my machines:

```
Tibuchina ~$ python
Python 2.6.7 (r267:88850, May 14 2012, 20:36:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('99') / 2
Decimal('2.21660407009470578688E-8')
>>>
```

I'm not sure where to look for a solution, and I haven't had any success searching for an answer - mostly because I'm not sure how to articulate the question.  Hoping someone has seen something similar and can suggest a solution.  Thanks!

-*edit*

Hmm, not exactly a dupe, but close; actually the answer with the Mintyfresh link (CppLearner) was most helpful as it pointed me in the right direction.  My python is brew installed, not mac ports, but ultimately the steps to fixing it were simply:

- Install Xcode command-line utils
- uninstall and reinstall python 2.6.7

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but I can confirm that this bug _doesn't_ exist in Python 2.6.7 (r267:88850, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin.

Comment: This might be the answer: http://blog.damacy.net/post/12104768819/compiling-macports-python-on-lion-using-gcc   search via `Compatible Apple Clang decimal python`

Comment: If you are on Mac, this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590137/dividing-decimals-yields-invalid-results-in-python-2-5-to-2-7

Comment: Uh, wow... that's kind of a nasty bug.